# Inheritance in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, master-pages

I'm new to asp.net C#, but I want to create a website that has one page with a grid view and a few buttons, that the all other pages will inherit, how can I do this? 
I tried using site.master and nested master pages but i think there is another way

Comment: I think user custom control (.ascx) will be an option. You can create a section (.ascx) file and then use that control in different pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try creating the grid view and buttons within a Custom Control, and then re-using the custom control across any pages that need it. You can define properties set in the pages containing the custom control if you need to customize anything, like the data source provided to the grid view.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e(v=vs.100).aspx